# PyAudio stream volume too low

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm playing a Pyaudio file every time OpenCV face detection returns a bounding box. So essentially for each coordinate update of the bounding box, we write wav data to the pyaudio stream. The stream plays the audio file on every face detection event like I want, but after just a few seconds of writing data to the stream the audio gets too quiet to hear.

I'm writing the audio data to the stream in the while loop below:

Full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys


CHUNK = 1024

wf = wave.open("audio files\light.wav", 'r')
print(wf.getframerate())

# instantiate PyAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play sound
# while len(data) > 0:
#     stream.write(data)
#     data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        stream.write(data)

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
# stop stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio
p.terminate()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading an arbitrary part of your sound (some frames that is) in your case `CHUNK = 1024` frames for some reason. What did you expect from that exactly? To be played part by part in each frame? From your context it seems that you want to play the whole sound, so, this is not the way to do it.

You should read all sound frames and write them at once:

```
data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
stream.write(data)
```

If on the other hand you are experiencing underrun problems you may consider solution proposed in answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20645941/3584765) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607612/3584765).

Comment: Eypros thanks for answering. When I do this and read the number of frames from the audio file, it only plays the audio file once at initiation of the first bounding box. But if I pass w (box width), then audio frames are only read when a rectangle exists and play according to it's width changes. This achieves a good motion detector like effect for the audio but I can't figure out the decreasing volume. Since the average width of the bounding boxes are about 500px, is the stream cutting off at around this many frames?